# Delete entire column with specific content in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

Have imported an excel sheet in python using pandas now,want to delete entire column with specific content as shown in in the snap [shot of content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHBt.png)

[image]

Here from this image want to delete entire column having content of **NAN** which represents no data entered, later the content can be used for computation purpose using pandas and graph could be plotted using myplotlib

Is there way to delete entire column based on content not on the base of label

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 s = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3,4], '2':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}) # example DataFrame
 s.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

It works fine..

Try this..

```
for col in s.columns:
    if False not in list(np.isnan(s[col])):
        del s[col]
```

Comment: here in the above case all the data that are going to be entered dynamical that is importing excel sheet so there are high chance that 'NaN' would move from Q.d/4 to Q.c/3 or any other column so in that case how to do that?

Comment: for that you will have to check the columns values for Nan